# Select table cell and save to session

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and never worked with sessions before.
So what I'm trying to do is, select a random table cell and store its location (x,y coordinates) to a new session. Here's my code so far, but I have to no idea what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, td, th {
            border: 2px solid green;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$rows = 10; // amout of tr
$cols = 10;// amount of td

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($tr=1; $tr<=$rows; $tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1; $td<=$cols; $td++){
               echo "<td>".$tr*$td."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/ and http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html first results found when Googling "php sessions tutorial"

Comment: To start, when the user selects a cell, you need to send a request to the webserver indicating which cell they have selected... an ajax request? a full page request? GET or POST from a form? Your choice

Answer (score 0):

If the random cell is to be chosen by the php code prior to the response from the server then you should just give the  elements an id such as cell0, cell1, cell2 and then use

```
$randomNum = rand(0,100);
```

to get a random number from 0 to 100 (change the 100 to your value). Then you can

```
$_SESSION["secretCell"] = "cell" . $randomNum;
```